# Limit order book - Behaviour of GTC orders in the Orderbook

Tags: equities, limit-order-book

If I made a GTC (good till cancelled) to a Stock Exchange how will it stay within the Orderbook of the Stock Exchange if not executed during the day? Will it be removed after the trading day is over and re added the next day? Or will it stay until it gets exectued or till I cancel it?

P.S.
If it is the first scenario will the GTC order also remain till the Stock Exchange's After Hours transaction period or any closing auctions are completed?